# Weird purple color in render using render farm (but not on my local computer)

Tags: rendering

I'm really new to blender and 3D overall. I've been using Conciergerender to render out my project, since I'm on a quite weak laptop.

In my render, I'm using a hdri for lighting an a background image using "import image as plane". My local render has the colors & light that I want, but the render using the render farm is all purple? And the lighting is way darker than my local render.

The only difference in settings are the amount of samples for the renders.

I read somewhere that purple is the default color for objects without texture, but the background image seems to be included correctly.

I just can't seem to find any information on why this happens and would need some help.

Thanks in advance <3

[image]

Comment: That usually happens when you don't pack all of the images into your blend file before you send it to the render farm, or the render farm can't deal with the packed images in some way.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks for the super quick reply! Oh yeah, I had totally forgot the step of File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend. It works great now. Thanks again! :)